# I deleted data from the dictionary and write dictionary's data to text file and got key error?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file which looks like this:
**myFiles.txt**

```
Dell    2015    A14523  Sam
Sony    2014    A74256  John
Acer    2018    A45656  Mark
Sony    2007    S12345  James
```

I want to delete the data when I give index as input so, I convert the text file into dictionary. By this way, I got indexes for my text file. But when I delete any data from the dictionary and write rest of data to text file a key error occur.
Because when I delete data from the dictionary,indexes remains the same
For example:
I have created 4 rows with for different key i.e. 1,2,3 and 4
When I delete the data from index 2 then dictionary indexes remains unchanged, I left with 1,3 and 4 and when I rewrite the data to text file it will give key error.
How can I delete data from text file.
I am new to python.Help me to solve it

```
def deleteFunction(self):
    ownerListDic = {}
    num = 1
    with open("myFiles.txt", "r") as oy:
        for line in oy:

            li = line.strip().split()
            ownerListDic[num] = {"name": li[0], "purchase": li[
                1], "bluePlate": li[2], "owner": li[3]}
            num += 1
    # enter the record id to delete from the text file
    indexId = int(input("Enter record ID: "))
    if indexId in ownerListDic:
        # prompting to confirm the user you are going to delete
        # this data
        print(("You arev about to delete " + ''.join(ownerListDic[indexId]['name'] +
                                                     " " + ownerListDic[indexId]['purchase'] + " " + ownerListDic[indexId]["bluePlate"] + " " + ownerListDic[indexId]['owner'])) + " .")
        # ask user to delete the data
        delete = input(
            "Do you wish to delete this record (Y/N): ").upper()
        # if yes then data will delete
        if delete == "Y":
            ownerListDic.pop(indexId, None)
            num=1
            with open("myFiles.txt", 'w') as log:
                for dataValue in ownerListDic.values():

                    log.write(ownerListDic[num]['name'] +
                              "\t" + ownerListDic[num]['purchase'] + "\t" + ownerListDic[num]["bluePlate"] + "\t" + ownerListDic[num]['owner'] + "\n")
                    num += 1

                # after deletion this message will print
                print("Record deleted.")
```

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `for num, dataValue in ownerListDic.items():`. That way, you'll write the actual key of the dictionary, rather than the index (which was the same thing before you deleted anything, but no longer is). I'm not sure whether you want to store that key in the file, so you can get back the same keys in subsequent runs, or not, but that's not much more difficult.

Comment: Worked well thanks alot sir Thankyou so much

Comment: Worked like a charm now i wonder i wasted a whole night try to find out the way to get the right answer..Thanks a lot sir